# PHP, MySql & JQuery - Filling select box after press add button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have several problems, I thought you should see my code :)

1. I have problem to fill the new select box when user click add button(or link) with get-data.php. When user click the add button(or link) then the new form include new select box displayed. When these html element displayed, my script can't filling the new select box element.
2. When the user type some text or fill all the element then they one to add new form, their previous text is gone.

Please guide me to solve this problem

Thanks in advance

**here is my html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
      var items="";
      $.getJSON("get-data.php",function(data){
        $.each(data,function(index,item) 
        {
          items+="<option value='"+item.id+"'>"+item.name+"</option>";
        });
        $("#mycollege").html(items); 
      });
    });
</script>
<form id="contact-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="form1" target="_parent">
    <fieldset>                                  
    <legend>EDUCATIONAL BACKGROUND</legend>
    <label><span class="text-form">College:</span><input type="radio" name="rad_college[]" value="1" />
    <select name="college[]" id="mycollege">
        <option value="">Default</option>
    </select>
    <input type="radio" name="rad_college[]" value="2" />Other<input type="text" name="college[]" style="float: none; margin-left: 10px;" />
    </label><br />

    <label><span class="text-form">Ladder:</span><input type="text" name="id_ladder[]" /></label><br />
    <label><span class="text-form">Majors:</span><input type="text" name="id_majors[]" /></label><br />
    <label><span class="text-form">Period:</span><input type="text" name="period[]" /></label><br />
    <label><span class="text-form">GPA:</span><input type="text" name="GPA[]" /></label><br />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var counter = 1;
        $("#add").click(function () {
            if(counter==800){
                alert("Too many boxes");
                return false;
            }
            $("#textBoxes").html($("#textBoxes").html() + "<div id='c"+counter+"' ><label for='t2'><span class='text-form'>College"+counter+":</span><input type='radio' name='rad_college"+counter+"[]' id='t"+counter+"' value='1' /><select name='college[]' id='mycollege'><option value=''>Default</option></select><input type='radio' name='rad_college"+counter+"[]' value='2' />Other<input type='text' name='college[]' style='float: none; margin-left: 10px;' /></label></div>\n");                                     
            $("#textBoxes").html($("#textBoxes").html() + "<div id='d"+counter+"' ><label for='t2'><span class='text-form'>Ladder"+counter+":</span><input type='text' name='id_ladder[]' id='t"+counter+"' /></label></div>\n");
            $("#textBoxes").html($("#textBoxes").html() + "<div id='e"+counter+"' ><label for='t2'><span class='text-form'>Majors"+counter+":</span><input type='text' name='id_majors[]' id='t"+counter+"' /></label></div>\n");
            $("#textBoxes").html($("#textBoxes").html() + "<div id='f"+counter+"' ><label for='t2'><span class='text-form'>Period"+counter+":</span><input type='text' name='period[]' id='t"+counter+"' /></label></div>\n");
            $("#textBoxes").html($("#textBoxes").html() + "<div id='g"+counter+"' ><label for='t2'><span class='text-form'>GPA"+counter+":</span><input type='text' name='GPA[]' id='t"+counter+"' /></label><br /><br /></div>\n");
            ++counter;
        });

        $("#remove").click(function () {
            if(counter==1){
                alert("Can u see any boxes");
                return false;
            }
            --counter;
            $("#c"+counter).remove();
            $("#d"+counter).remove();
            $("#e"+counter).remove();
            $("#f"+counter).remove();
            $("#g"+counter).remove();
        });
    });
    </script>

    <div id="textBoxes">
        <!-- <br /> -->
        <br />
    </div>
    <br />

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="add" class="button">add</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="remove" class="button">remove</a>

    <br /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset">
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**here is my php code: (get-data.php)**

```
<?php
include 'configurations/db-connections.php';

$q = "select id, name from college";
$sql = mysql_query($q);
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, true)){
    $data[] = $row; 
};
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Did you trace the request? Are you actually getting back the JSON data? Does your request actually run?

Comment: I don't know how to trace jquery. Yes I got data back from php json encode (I thought) . My request is run correctly but when the user click new form data then can't fill into the new form. Could you please guide me to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

According to your answer on my comment, you need to debug the Javascript first..., if you don't know how, check out this tutorial: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/13/debugging-javascript-with-chrome.aspx

After you've read it and try it on your code, let me know what appears to be wrong, I'll edit this answer and I'll try to help you solve your issue.